# Hosting many web apps under different domain names

Tags: iis-6, web-hosting, domain-name

I've created a domain name and I've changed the DNS to my hosting machine IP.

No problem with that. I host a few web applications on my machine, all under the same IP address. They're all stored as myserver.com/web1, myserver.com/web2, etc.

However, I want http://mynewdomain.com to be redirected to myserver.com/web2 without the user knowing. So that all links with relative paths would show up with the new domain name like http://mynewdomain.com/news would make IIS fetch it from /web2/news.

I hope my question is clear enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just setup the virtual domain configurations correctly on/through your web server?

Comment: Wouldn't I need an unique IP for each web app then?

Comment: Good deal... Easy and clean...